# How to get random Wikipedia articles of a specific category and grade?

Tags: wikipedia

How do I get random articles from a specific category, with a [quality grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Content_assessment#Grades) of **GA** or better?

The following works (but doesn't support grades): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own tool for that. The [publicly available database replica](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Toolforge/Database) includes [a random number](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_random) for each page, you'll have to reimplement the RandomInCategory logic on top of that, with an extra condition for the [page_assessments table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageAssessments/page_assessments_table) thrown in.